# Meaning of "just" and "you" in imperative sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Oh,  to  hell  with  your  stars  and  constellations!”  the  three  on  the  ground  yelled,  almost  in unison. “**Just** come **you** down"

This paragraph is from a fable. I can't decide the usage of "just", and "you".
In my opinion, "just" means " to get attention for order " and "you" are used "for emphating anger".

Comment: **come you** is an archaism preserved in regional dialects.Compare **come ye**.

Answer (score 1):

"Come you down" is an archaic imperative form, whose meanign would now be expressed by "you come down" or even "come down, you". In any case it is a command to the person addressed to come down.

Other similar forms were "Come you on"  (meaning "advance!") and "Come you nigh" (meaning "Come here!" or "come near me").

related forms:

> Come the three corners of the world in arms, and we shall shock them.

(Shakespeare, *King john* Act V scene vii) (Meaning: "If all the world approaches and attacks, we will fight them off)

> Come one, Come all

(An invitation to everyone)

> Come ye to Bethlehem

(*Oh Come all ye Faithful* a command to everyone to travel to Bethlehem for the birth of Jesus)

> Hear Ye, Hear Ye

(A command that everyone listen and pay attention)

In short. “Just come you down" meas simply "Just come down" and is a command.